# understanding unit test using visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I need help on the unit testing. I have never done a code unit test through Visual studio and can't seem to find any videos or reading material on how to create one using just Visual Studio 2010 Professional. Everything I find is in reference in one way or another to testing center and I don't have it, nor can I get a full version of it (broke student).
When I try to d a unit test i see all this extra stuff generated and I don't understand any of it, I can tell that some of it has to be updated after generated but don't know to what for the given situation. Is there any free resource that i can use that will tell me how to make a unit test? I would even be happy learning how to make them from scratch.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: It's a general question. It will seem unclear to you if your are looking for an exact case. I'm asking as a beginner, how to do unit testing in visual studio 2010 professional, where can i find, resources that will give me more information on doing a unit test. If you read I also stated I'm a student so that also lets you know i'm not a senior level developer so with answer you should KISS (Keep It Simple Silly). The other, Poom and Ian seem to understand, not sure why you all didn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to understand is that a unit test in C# is created and run with a reference to a library which supports unit testing. Microsoft provide MSTest, and there are alternatives. A very popular one is NUnit.

Most test frameworks work with attributes. An attribute in this context is the bit which decorates the code using square brackets:

```
[ThisIsAnAttribute]
public void ThisMethodIsDecoratedWithAnAttribute(){}
```

Attributes provide additional information which can be retrieved at runtime using reflection. Reflection allows you to inspect the structure of the code and types in that code.

Most testing frameworks use two main concepts. 1) A "Fixture" which is a snazzy way of saying "A set of tests" and 2) a "Test". A fixture is represented by a class with a fixture attribute, tests are represented by methods with a test attribute.

The tests are obviously testing something, so you need two things here as well. 1) The thing you are testing and 2) A way to "Assert" that the test has passed or failed.

So the thing you are testing is just code. Generally this should be a small bit of code which is independent and isolated. Tests should never really be longer than 20 lines max (although remember to never say never).

To Assert that a test has passed or failed you use a class from the testing framework which feeds back test success. This is usually called Assert and is static.

So to assert that a value at the end of a test is a certain value, you might say:

```
Assert.IsEqualTo(5, myResultVariable);
```

The Assert class has a lot of methods. These will test for various conditions. Is it null, is it equal to, is it not equal to, that sort of thing.

To run the test, you use the framework's runner. This will take the code and report back the results.

So here's a simple MSTest unit test.

```
[TestClass]
public class MathTestsForSimpleOperators
{        
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestThatAdding3To8Equals11()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(11, 3 + 8);
    }
}
```

You can see the fixture is called MathTestsForSimpleOperators (Be descriptive) and it has one test called TestThatAdding3To8Equals11. It's not a useful test, but it has all the parts you need.

Here is a link to NUnit's getting started page. MSTest is just as simple to use. It will take you through step by step installing, writing and running a test.
[NUnit getting started page](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=getStarted&r=2.6.3)

Answer (score 1):

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-beginners-guide-to-unit-testing-what-is-unit-testing--wp-25728

Maybe?

Another suggestion, try doing thins your self, and when you are stuck just don't hestitate to ask this community. But don't just ask for whole help to your projects.

Poom

Comment: Thanks, your information was helpful. I was actually looking for information on C# but the info is good in general, and I actually am also working on some PHP code on the side to so this will help me with that also. It will not let me raise the level on your answer because i don't have a high enough reputation... I have to say that the way they do the comments and privileges on here is stupid because they give power to the ignorant to modify and remove your questions, and comments but don't give you a way to contest it. In addition, they allow others to effect your "reputation"

Comment: Yes I understand , my answer isn't that useful. I'm glad you like it. I can't comment too so I have to answer